# how to get record from store without using load function in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I have the json response with totalCount Values. I am getting the totalCount value in a load function. I am creating store in controller before loading store If(totalCount>0). It is executing the else condition. Can anybody tell me how to load store and check the conditon?. Is it possible to get a record from a field without load function?

```
var totalCount=0;
store.load(
    { 
        scope: this,    
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {  
             totalCount = records[0].data.totalCount    
        }
    }
);

if (totalCount > 0) {
    console.log("record found");
} else {
    console.log("record not found");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the `store.load` function is asynchronous. That means your code immediately following the call to `load` will execute before the `load` function returns.  Your `callback` function gets called much later than the `if` statements get executed.

To answer your actual question in the title of your post look in the API: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

Depending on what you need you can use any number of methods: `.getRange()` to get an array or `.each()` to immediately iterate over records.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your evaluation of `totalCount` is probably occurring before the load callback is executed.  Since you initialize `totalCount` to 0 before the call to load the store, that's what the value is when you're evaluating it.  Move the console logging into your callback function to verify this.